# Google Maps Geocoder: Reference Position for Plain Location Names

Tags: google-maps, geocode

I'm using the google maps api for geocoding addresses. If I geocode a plain location name (e.g. Munich) the api returns corresponding latitude and longitude.

To which position do these coordinates refer to? Is it the (geographical) center of the location or the position of the administrative headquarter or what else?

Answer (score 0):

They refer to the equator which is latitude=0° and the  prime meridian which is longitude=0°. This represents the central point (starting point).

You can look at it as to the Cartesian coordinate system starting from (0,0)=(x,y) and retrieving all the other places by changing the x(long) and y(lat) coordinates. So yes, the answer is geographical centre.

**EDIT:**
url (video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Spel7vfkpNc starting at *2:43*

Basically, companies within the country decide on which lat, long will a city, country when searched appear. For example if you are searching for London the pin point will be assigned to particular coordinates depending on the company decision.

Comment: My bad, I should have be more precisely. What I meant was, which point does google actually return if the location is an area of e.g 100 square kilometers like a whole city.

Comment: Watch the video starting from 2:43 and hopefully you will get your answer

Comment: Well ok, the company (in this particular case: Google?) decides. So if they don't just throw a dart at a map, there may be some kind of logic behind their decision. This logic (ideally an algorithm if any) is what I'm seeking for.